# How to find device node on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, usb, terminal

I'm trying to get a Roland iModela to work on my Mac. Even if stated otherwise by the manufacturer this machine is able to be run by other OS than Windows. I already got it working on a Linux with `cat mygcode.ngc > /dev/usb/lp0` where lp0 is the node for the machine. But now I'm stuck as I'm unable figure out how to find the correct device node under OSX. What's the right command? `dmesg` doesn't tell anything about it :-(

Answer (score 0):

On Roland's [support page](http://icreate.rolanddg.com/iModela/DGA/English/support/faq.html/), to the question in the '*About Specifications*' section

> **Can this be used with a Mac?**

the answer is a simple

> **No.**

A search on Google for [MacOS USB device prober](https://www.google.ca/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=mac%20os%20x%20usb%20prober&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&redir_esc=&ei=GpaXUYLsF7iv4AO72YCwDg) gave this [Apple Developer Library article](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1370/_index.html).

Comment: You're not reading my question at that part where I point out that it IS possible even if Roland says it ain't? They also state it is not possible on Linux, but it is. So please focus on "how to find a specific device node under OSX" as it can be talked to like a generic text-only printer so only the device node is needed...

Comment: Oh, I read what you said, and what the docs said just fine.   I didn't see any mention where the docs said it couldn't be used with Linux...  Just Mac.  You might actually want to direct your inquiry to the folks to whom you've paid money, who also have salaried software developers who have a vested interest in making their product work for Mac users like yourself.  However, as a volunteer provider of technical support...

Comment: Sorry, no offense Nevin. It's great that you're actually go in for my question. It's not that I paid money for it, Roland gave our FabLab one and I want to provide help to others that might have problems. On the support page you mentioned Roland also states: "Q: Does iModela operate on Linux?" - "A: No. It is not compatible with Linux operating system." And that's just wrong too, so as MacOSX is a *NIX OS there has to be a device node somewhere. Besides that this question is about iModela, how can one find out what device uses which node?

Comment: Actually, I did not see any reference to Linux; I stopped reading as soon as I got to Mac. 

See my edited answer for the clarification you requested.